# Assign value is garbage or undefined

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, undefined, garbage

I have posted screenshot of my error code.
[image]

`heights` output

[image]

please any one can help me?

Comment: what is the value of `_numberOfColumns`?

Comment: _numberOfColumms = 2;

Comment: I suspect your for loop to assign the value in array han't executed...May be _numberOfColumns = 0. Can you print the contents of heights array?

Comment: Also, check if `malloc` has successfully allocated memory by checking `if(NULL == heights) printf("Not enough memory\n");`

Comment: hi i checked code as your guys said, _numberOfColumns = 2 & height is not null.

Comment: why have you written continue at the end of first loop?

Comment: Make sure that `(heights[i] != nil)`

Comment: @ravijimagna: continue wont affect any thing, That is waste however.

Comment: @RomitMewada: One stupid suggestion, why dont you use NSMutableArray?

Comment: Please show us the array contents...It can be helpful

Comment: It looks to me like the static analyzer is wrong; your code looks OK to me.

Comment: This looks OK. You should ignore the analyzer if code is working properly without any strange behaviour.

Comment: @trojanfoe The analyzer is correct, because `_numberOfColumns` could be 0, therefor making `heights[0]` garbage.

Comment: @Sebastian No, the analyzer states that value **is** garbage, not **could be** garbage, so it's at least inaccurate.

Comment: @trojanfoe I've never seen the analyzer telling me that something **could be** wrong...

Comment: @Sebastian So you've never seen the message "Potential leak of an object allocated on line ..."?

Comment: you're right, I've seen that one.

Answer (score 3):

I think the static analyzer is not seeing how `_numberOfColumns` can become non-zero, and hence its insistence that garbage is being assigned.  You need to check that you are actually providing some means for `_numberOfColumns` to become non-zero.

Generally when I am writing loops that want to find the largest or the smallest value, I initialize the *size* variable to the largest (if I want the smallest) or smallest (if I want the largest) amount, and I think this will solve most of your issues:

```
float shortestHeight = FLT_MAX;
for (unsigned i = 0; i < _numberOfColumns; i++)
{
    // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The analyzer is correct. Your code will access garbage memory if `_numberOfColumns` is 0, thus allocating 0 bytes for `heights`, making `heights[0]` garbage. The analyzer doesn't know what values `_numberOfColumns` can have, but you can tell it by using `assert(_numberOfColumns>0)`.

Take this C program for example:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int n = argc-1;
    int *a = malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        a[i] = i;
    }
    int foo = a[0];
    free(a);
    return foo;
}
```

the size of `a` is determined by the number of arguments. If you have no arguments `n == 0`. If you are sure that your program (or just that part of your program) will always assign something greater than 0 to `a`, you can use an assertion. Adding `assert(n>0)` will tell the analyzer exactly that.